# Why are the company-mode's drop downs ragged?

Tags: fonts, company-mode, company

Here is how my [company-mode's](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode) drop-downs look,

[image]
[image]

As you can tell, they are uneven, ugly and somehow a different font than what my Emacs is using ([Iosevka](https://github.com/be5invis/Iosevka/)). I found [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9545/ragged-menu-in-company-mode), but did not quite understand the answer. It was also asked back in 2015 so maybe there is a better answer now?

My emacs is `GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2019-09-16` and company-mode is at `20200324.2145`. I am using doom-theme atom one.

I want the drop downs to look like they do in the screenshots present on the [company-mode's website](https://company-mode.github.io/).

Is there a way to achieve this? I looked for configs pertaining to the company's drop downs but could not find anything. Is this a font issue? If so, could I just use a different font for company's drop downs (something that is not uneven), which font? Any recommendations? Maybe set it using [use-package's custom face](https://jwiegley.github.io/use-package/keywords/#custom-face) attribute?

Is there anything else I am missing or is there an easier solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using a variable-width font, not a fixed-width font, for those menu items.  Find out which Emacs face is used for Company menu items, and change its font to a fixed-width font by using `M-x customize-face`.

I don't use Company, but a quick look at [`company-template.el`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/company-mode/company-mode/master/company-template.el), which is where its faces are defined, suggests that maybe the face you need to customize is `company-tooltip`.

Try:

```lisp
;; company
(use-package company
  :ensure t
  :custom-face
  (company-tooltip
   ((t (:family "Iosevka")))))
```

Comment: I had to use `M-x customize-face` to set the font family of `company-tooltip` variable. That fixed the raggedness. If you incorporate that in your answer, I'll accept it.